# How multiple indexes in postgres work on the same column

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I was wondering I'm not really sure how multiple indexes would work on the same column.

So lets say I have an id column and a country column. And on those I have an index on id and another index on id and country. When I do my query plan it looks like its using both those indexes. I was just wondering how that works? Can I force it to use just the id and country index.

Also is it bad practice to do that? When is it a good idea to index the same column multiple times?

Comment: I would start with posting the table definitions, the query and the plan.

Comment: Generally, you can drop the index on `id` if you have an index on `id, country`. Except when `id` index is used for `PK` or `UNIQUE` check.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to have indexes on both (id) and (country,id), or alternatively (country) and (country,id) if you have queries that benefit from each of them.  You might also have (id) and (id, country) if you want the "covering" index on (id,country) to support index only scans, but still need the stand along to enforce a unique constraint.

In theory you could just have (id,country) and still use it to enforce uniqueness of id, but PostgreSQL does not support that at this time.

You could also sensibly have different indexes on the same column if you need to support different collations or operator classes.

If you want to force PostgreSQL to not use a particular index to see what happens with it gone, you can drop it in a transactions then roll it back when done:

BEGIN; drop index table_id_country_idx; explain analyze select * from ....; ROLLBACK;